# Why do I get [...] when I append a list to the same list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code was tried in a Python 2.7.1 interpreter.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> a == a[-1]
True
>>> print a[-1]
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

Can anyone please explain what python is trying to do here?

Comment: If you want to put two lists together just do: `[1,2,3]+[4,5,6]` which will produce `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an infinite nested list inside your list. As it can not be represented, `[...]` appears.

Take a look at what happens if you try to print each value:

```
>>> for item in a:
...     print item
... 
1
2
3
[1, 2, 3, [...]] # The whole list that we just iterated over :)
```

Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-is-in-python-2-7) for further reading.

Answer (score 2):

Youre basically making a list of nested list (list within lists) and youre appending a list to itself creating a infinitely nested list

for example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> 

>>> a[3]
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>> a[3][3]
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>>
```

When you do `a[3]` its showing the next list in the nested list when i do `a[3][3]` Im getting the list within `a[3]` the `[...]` is how python portrays this idea

More information and example explaining these infinitely nested lists [here](http://asmeurersympy.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/infinitely-nested-lists-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Lists are assigned as pointers to the original lists. 
If you truly want a list appended as element 3 you can make a copy like this:

```
>>> a.append(a[:])
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]
```

or if you want the elements of `a`, instead use:

```
>>> a = a + a
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```