# python list assigning values of a member of a list to the list itself

Tags: python, list

I’m reading the book “Practical Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science Using Python 3”. In Chapter 8 (Lists), there is a question in the book as follows:

> - **Draw a memory model showing the effect of the following statements**
>
>   ```
>   values = [0,1,2]
>   values[1] = values
>   ```

Why does `print values` show `[0, [...], 2]`? Shouldn't it be `[0, [0,1,2], 2]`?

Comment: `...` means ellipsis, and it would be: `[0, [0, [0, [0, [0, [0, [0, [0, [...], 2], 2], 2], 2,], 2], 2], 2], 2]`

Comment: Dup: [What is `[…]` in Python 2.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-is-in-python-2-7)