# Append a list to a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, append

I have a list of numbers and I want to extract *N* elements as lists, and store them in another list.
Example:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
resultList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I've done the following

```
def getLines(square, N):
    i = 0

    line  = [None]*N
    lines = list()

    for elt in square:
        line[i] = elt
        i += 1
        if i == N:
            lines.append(line)
            i = 0

return lines
```

Why do I always get the last list three times

```
[[7,8,9],[7,8,9],[7,8,9]]
```

when I call the function `getLines(list1, 3)`.

I also tried to eliminate the temporary list and add the elements directly to `resultList` like this:

```
def getLines(square, N):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    lines = [[None]*N]*N # Need to be initialized to be able to index it.

    for elt in square:
        lines[i][j] = elt
        j += 1
        if j == N:
            i += 1
            j = 0

return lines
```

The last group is still appearing *N* times. Any hints on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating only one inner list object, and altering it.
In pseudocode, what you are doing is:

- Create a list called `line` assigning `[None, None, None]` to it
- Create an empty list called `lines`
- For three times:
  -- Pick n items from the `square` list
  -- Assign these three items to `line[0]`, `line[1]` and `line[2]`
  --  Append `line` to `lines`

So, what you are doing is assigning to *individual items* of `line`. This is important - you're not making a new object each time, you're changing individual items in the `line` list.
At the end of it all, `line` will point to the list `[7, 8, 9]`. And you can see `lines` as being substantially `[line, line, line]` (a list of three times the same object), so specifically now it will point to `[[7,8,9], [7,8,9], [7,8,9]]`.

To solve this, possibly the solution that most keeps your original code is to re-define `line` after appending it. This way, the variable name `line` will refer to a different list each time, and you won't have this problem.

```
def getLines(square, N):
    i = 0

    line  = [None]*N
    lines = list()

    for elt in square:
        line[i] = elt
        i += 1
        if i == N:
            lines.append(line)
            line  = [None]*N # Now `line` points to a different object
            i = 0

    return lines
```

Of course, there is leaner, more Pythonic code that can do the same thing (I see that an answer has already been given).

**EDIT - Ok, here goes a somehow more detailed explanation.**
Perhaps one of the key concepts is that lists are not containers of other objects; they merely hold references to other objects.
Another key concept is that when you change an item in a list (item assignment), you're not making the whole list object become another object. You're merely changing a reference inside it. This is something we give for granted in a lot of situations, but somehow becomes counter-intuitive when we'd want things to go the other way and "recycle" a list.

As I was writing in the comments, if `list` was a cat named **Fluffy**, every time you're appending you're creating a mirror that points to Fluffy. So you can dress Fluffy with a party hat, put a mirror pointing to it, then give Fluffy a clown nose, put on another mirror, then dress Fluffy as a ballerina, add a third mirror, and when you look at the mirrors, all three of them will show the *ballerina* Fluffy. (Sorry Fluffy).

What I mean is that in practice **in your first script**, when you do the append:

```
    lines.append(line)
```

by the first concept I mentioned, you are not making `lines` *contain* the current status of `line` as a separate object. You are appending a reference to the `line` list.

And when you do,

```
    line[i] = elt
```

by the second concept, of course `line` is always the same object; you're just changing what's referenced at the *i-th* position.

This is why, at the end of your script, `lines` will appear to "contain three identical objects": because you actually appended three references to the same object. And when you ask to see the content of `lists`, you will read, three times, the `list` object in its current status.

In the code I provided above, I re-define the name `lists` to make it reference a *brand new* list every time it's been appended to `lists`:

```
        lines.append(line)  
        line  = [None]*N # Now `line` points to a different object
```

This way, at the end of the script I have "three different cats" appended, and each one was conveniently named Fluffy just until I had appended it, to give room for a new Fluffy list after that.

Now, in your **second script**, you do something similar. The key instruction is:

```
    lines = [[None]*N]*N # Need to be initialized to be able to index it.
```

In this line, you are creating two objects:
 - the list `[None, None, None]`
 - the list named `lines`, which contains N references to the same list `[None, None, None]`.

What you did was just to create straight away Fluffy and the three mirrors pointing at him.
In fact if you change `lines[0][2]`,  or `lines[1][2]`, you're just changing the same item [2] of your same Fluffy.

What you actually wanted to do is,

```
    lines = [[None]*N for i in range(N)]
```

which creates three different cats - I mean, lists, and have `lines` point to the three.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But why does "lines" get appended only the last "line" ? I am changing "line" each time, shouldn't it be appended each time (in the if statement) ?

Comment: @Ouss4 That's not the way you should see it. There is a crucial difference (which will be the specific thing you'll have learned by solving this issue), between naming an object, and assigning individually to an item in an object.

Comment: @Ouss4 try to see it like this:  
I have a cat called Fluffy. (1) I'll put a green hat on it.  
I'll have a mirror point at Fluffy.  
(2) Now I'm going to put a clown hat on it.  
I'll have a second mirror point at Fluffy.  
(3) Now I'm going to dress it like a ballerina.  
I'll have a third mirror point at Fluffy.  
  
(4) And curiously enough, all the three mirrors show Fluffy dressed as a ballerina now. ...so in order for this to work, you need to use three cats (three different objects) instead of changing the hat on the same cat.

Comment: Sorry, how could we apply the same reasoning to the second code snippet I gave? Shouldn't it change each value of "lines"?

Comment: @Ouss4 it's the same basically. I'll edit my answer when I get home, it's too lengthy to write here, but you're basically just building up front the three mirrors that point to the same cat.

Comment: @Ouss4 for added wow factor, try this: `a = [None]`, `a[0] = a` then check `a`. Infinite mirrors!

Comment: It looks like Fluffy is facing a mirror and looking through this mirror to another mirror behind. (Well I get [[...]], some googling tells that it represents an infinite data structures with ellipses. Is that accurate?) Edit: It looks like we have some explanations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-is-in-a-python-list)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider solving this like:

```
def getLines(square, N):
    return [square[i:i + N] for i in range(0, len(square), N)]
```

For example: `getLines([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3)` will return `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`, or `getLines([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2)` results in `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]`, and so on.

Comment: That's really neat thank you. I was going to try to do it with list comprehension, but got caught trying to solve the last problem.