# Python - List returning [[...], 6]

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I run the following code

```
data = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

for x in data:
    print(x[0])

for x[0] in data:
    print(x)
```

I get the following output

```
1
3
5
[[1, 2], 6]
[[3, 4], 6]
[[...], 6]
```

I end up with a list containing `[[...], 6]`, but what is this `[...]` list?

It doesn't behave normally, because calling `y = [[...], 6]` and then the following statements show `[...]` to be `0`

```
>>> print(y)
[[Ellipsis], 6]

>>> print(y[0])
[0]
```

However when I run the code at the top, and type the following statements the results don't make sense:

```
>>> print(x)
[[...], 6]

>>> print(x[0])
[[...], 6]

>>> print(x[0][0])
[[...], 6]

>>> print(x[0][0][0])
[[...], 6]
```

and yet somehow both of these result in 6

```
>>> print(x[1])
6

>>> print(x[0][1])
6
```

To review the question: How is this possible, and what does `[...]` represent, and how can the for loop at the top create such a list?

Comment: Did you do any research? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-do-ellipsis-mean-in-a-list

Comment: Strangely I couldn't find that question from my searches, it seems to answer the question perfectly. The only question that remains unanswered is how does the for loop create such a list? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Because each step of the loop assigns the next element from `x` to `x[0]`. Those two loops are **not** the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's give your sublists names:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]
data = [a, b, c]
```

Your first loop binds `a`, `b` and `c` successively to `x`. When the loop terminates, you have effectively set `x = c`.

The second loop now binds `a`, `b` and `c` successively to `x[0]`. This is fine for `a` and `b`, but for `c` you are effectively doing `c[0] = c`, creating a circular reference. Since `list` is able to catch that, it won't try to print `[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[`...

Answer (score 5):

that's because you're using `x[0]` as your loop variable (which is bad practice) which exists as a list and not a new name like you're supposed to when iterating with `for`

```
for x[0] in data:
    print(x)
```

and `x` is in `data` so there's a cyclic reference (hence the [ellipsis representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-do-ellipsis-mean-in-a-list) to avoid infinite recursion when printing the same data over and over)

*More in detail*:

The ellipsis happens on the last element because of the previous loop that binds `x` on the last element of `data` (`[5,6]`).

So the second loop assigns `[5,6]` to `x[0]` but it's also `x`. On way to get rid of this is to create a copy of `x` just before the second loop: `x = x[:]`

Comment: Great answer, so the […] represents an infinite loop of the same list?

Comment: `...` is the way to represent something that cycles.