# Append list to itself in python

Tags: python, list, recursion, append, python-3.8

When I have a list, say `mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and I try to append it to its self

```
mylist.append(mylist)
```

I get

```
['a', 'b', 'c', [...]]
```

Which is a recursive list, for example, `mylist[3][3][1]` outputs `'b'`

I expected to get

```
['a', 'b', 'c', ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

My first question is how can I get what I expected (if there are many methods I would prefer the most performant).
My second question, is what's the reason for this "unexpected" behaviour.
Thanks.

I use `python3.8.2`

Comment: Covered in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-do-ellipsis-mean-in-a-list)

Comment: Use: mylist.append(mylist[:])

Comment: You are adding the `mylist` object inside `mylist`. any changes in `mylist` will be reflected in both of them if you are mutating them in-place.

Comment: You may want to read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). `append` *always* adds a reference to an object to a list, so you are adding a reference to the list to itself.

Comment: The way around this is to append a *copy* of the list: `l.append(l[:])`, so that it no longer points to the original list and there's no recursion

Comment: Hey @yatu It is not right to close the question, the other question you point to is just an explanation to the meaning of [...], but there it is no direct answer to my question. How to append a list to itself. So please, reopen. By the way thanks for giving an answer, though as commentary, please post it as a normal answer :)

Comment: The explanation is clear from the duplicate. There is recursion because the list being appended points to the same object. You need to append a *copy* of the list

Comment: I've also added a dupe covering the concept of *copying*

Comment: Well, I just disagree, the other question is like an encyclopedia answer. If I am no expert, it is an overkill, and somehow I spend a lot of time to find the right answer, which @Orestis Zekai posted in few lines.

Comment: Ok, yatu, now looks better. Nevertheless, `l.append(l[:])` should be added as an answer for the sake of somebody looking quick for the solution.

Comment: Well you did ask for *the reason for this "unexpected" behaviour*, which may be a bit complicated to if you're no *expert* as you put it. But it is the actual explanation of what's happening. Once you understand that, it becomes clear that what you need is to append a copy. Give the dupes a good read, it'll help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
mylist.append([x for x in mylist])
```