# Private Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

In python language, all are global by default. Same way, inheritance. We can't inherit a base class in private or protected visibility mode. But, why is this setup doesn't give that option to inherit with visibility modes???

Comment: No it is not possible. If you want to use functionality of class A in class B without making B a subtype of A, consider composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Since Python has metaclasses, you can fully customise what a class is or how it is constructed, including what it means to inherit from another class. So yes, "it is possible". Whether you should actually *do* that, or whether you actually *want* that instead of something else is hard to tell. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you need (e.g. in terms of desired syntax or desired behaviour) to show volunteers that the effort to sketch a solution is a) correct and b) desirable?

Comment: Please don't just edit your question into a completely new one. If you have a new question, post it as a separate question.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17160162/12500840) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't do the public/private/protected inheritance of c++.

It's somewhat a feature of python that you can access anything. If you want strong encapsulation you have to look at other languages.

Answer (score -2):

Names beginning with double underscores are effectively private - see [Private name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers).