# What does a [..., 0] mean in python array?

Tags: python, arrays

What is the meaning of ... in a python array?
The code below is what it was written like.

```
 obj = target[..., 0 ]
```

Please help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do ellipsis \[...\] mean in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-do-ellipsis-mean-in-a-list)

Comment: To clarify: is this part of your code, or something your program printed out? Are you using numpy, or something like it?

Comment: It was part of someone's code and I wanted to figure it out. Numpy was used.

Comment: I guess this doesn't mean a loop as in the link above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the ellipsis slicing syntax in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118370/how-do-you-use-the-ellipsis-slicing-syntax-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Ellipsis expands to all other dimensions.

From numpy's [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> Ellipsis expands to the number of : objects needed for the selection tuple to index all dimensions.
>
> Example for a 3 dimensional shape:
>
> ```
> >>> x = np.array([[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]])
> >>> x.shape
> (2, 3, 1)
> >>> x[...,0]
> array([[1, 2, 3],
>       [4, 5, 6]])
> ```

You can see that the first item of the third dimension was picked across all others. Since it contains only 1 item and is not a slice, it was expanded.

Answer (score 0):

In numpy arrays, an ellipsis (`...`) is the equivalent of a column (`:`) in that they allow array slicing like in the example below where I create a 2D numpy array and print its columns as 1D array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(range(12)).reshape(3,4)
print(f'x = {x}')
print(f'\nSlicing with ellipsis \t Slicing with column')
for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    print(f'{x[...,i]} \t\t {x[:,i]}')
```

The output of this code is:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]

Slicing with ellipsis    Slicing with column
[0 4 8]                  [0 4 8]
[1 5 9]                  [1 5 9]
[ 2  6 10]               [ 2  6 10]
[ 3  7 11]               [ 3  7 11]
```

The same could be done on rows using `x[i,:]` or its equivalent `x[i,...]`.

Comment: Actually ellipses can substitute one or more consecutive colons https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-numpy-ellipsis/