# How does Python generate this result due to circular reference?

Tags: python, list, circular-reference

I'm reading on Python variables, objects and references, and stumbled on the notion of circular reference. The book presents an example:

```
L = [1,2]
L.append(L)
L
```

I tried on Python, the result is:

```
[1,2, [...]]
```

I kind of understand circular reference but not sure how Python generates this result, I mean, where it starts, where it goes on and how it ends up with this list. Very much appreciate if any one could help explain this.

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-do-ellipsis-mean-in-a-list). Are you asking how Python print internally recognizes that it's circular?

Comment: `L.__repr__` simply detects that the list element it has to produce a string for is `L`, and use `[...]` instead of recursively calling `L.__repr__`.

Comment: Something like `x += '[...]' if x is self else repr(x)` in the definition `def __repr__(self): ...`.

Comment: (It's a little more complicated, because it can detect deeper cycles as well, such as `L = [1, 2]; C = [3, 4, L]; L.append(L)`.)