# append function in python

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list `X = ['xyz']`

I use the below commands for appending to another variable.

```
L = X

L.append(X)

L

Out[109]: ['xyz', [...]]
```

I am unable to understand why the second element in the new L list is not having the value as 'xyz'

My question is not how to append or extend a list, but in fact about the functionality of Append function, which has been correctly explained by @sinsuren below.

Comment: Er, you seem to have appended a list to itself. What did you think would happen?

Comment: You might want to use `extend()` instead.

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicate, I don't understand.  :( :(

My question is not how to append or extend a list, but in fact about the functionality of Append function, which has been correctly explained by @sinsuren below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will extend the list.

```
L.extend(X)
```

But if you want to use  `append`. Use a element like this `L.append('abc')`. It will give same result or `L.append(X[0])`

Edit:
 You have Appended list to itself. It will recursively append to itself and due to which even `L[1]` will give you same response. Like `L[1] = ['xyz', [...]]` . and for more understanding Please refer [What's exactly happening in infinite nested lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674685/whats-exactly-happening-in-infinite-nested-lists)

Comment: Any rule about, when not to use 'append' function in specific ?

Comment: If you want to put an element there, use append. If you want to make your list longer by chaining on another list at the end, use extend.

Comment: @Moberg, why does it work OK then in the example below ?

`>>> x = [1,2,3]`
`>>> y = [4,5,6]`
`>>> x.append(y)`
`>>> x`
`[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]`

Comment: Ya, that was expected.

But my initial question was, why the second element in the resultant list is blank ?

Comment: When you assigned L with X both share same reference.  So you appended a list to itself which holds same reference. and it seems like infinite `Like Inception Movie`

Comment: https://ideone.com/OOYGP0 Here you can see this also.

Comment: @sinsuren, Thanks I got it now !

Comment: Sure, thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

`append` add `X` as an element to `L`. If you want the element inside `X` to be inserted to `L`, use `extend` instead:

```
>>> X = ['xyz']
>>> L = X
>>> L.extend(X)
>>> L
['xyz', 'xyz']
```