# Compare deeply nested lists safely?

Tags: python, stack-overflow

The following simple comparison of pure lists explodes on me:

```
a, b = [], []
for _ in range(1000):
    a, b = [a], [b]
a == b
```

Python 3.5.1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    a == b
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Python 2.7.11:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    a == b
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Does the language/library offer a safe way to compare such deeply nested lists, or will I have to write my own iterative comparison code?

Edit: I'm asked to explain why my question isn't a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674685/whats-exactly-happening-in-infinite-nested-lists). It isn't because that one is about *infinite* nesting and because I'm not asking for an explanation (I understand it already) but for whether Python offers a simple solution.

Comment: You seriously have lists that are nested more than 1000 levels? That sounds like a problem in and of itself.

Comment: If this is a real situation, you know what recursion depth you'll need, and you're reasonably sure that your machine can handle such a depth, you can increase the maximum recursion depth.

Comment: @Falmarri No I don't actually have this, I just got curious when I noticed that the above doesn't work. But I don't see why a nested structure with 1000 or more levels would be a problem in general.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It's not a "real" situation for me, I'm just curious. Under a recent question about a recursive list-comparison function, someone commented that the professor shouldn't use that to teach recursion because it should be done iteratively. Then I tested the above and saw that Python itself also does it recursively. Didn't bother telling them that, but it inspired my above curiosity.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Interesting find. While checking this out in the shell for myself, it seems `__repr__`  is implemented recursively too.