# How to fix "zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity" in keras pad_sequences

Tags: python, keras

Recently faced with such a problem: ValueError: array of size zero up to the maximum of the cast operation, having no identity.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import unicodedata
import string
import numpy as np
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
keras = tf.keras
```

```
class Lang(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.word2int = {} #maps words to integers
        self.word2count = {} #maps words to their total number in the corpus
        self.int2word = {0 : "SOS", 1 : "EOS"} #maps integers to tokens (just the opposite of word2int but has some initial values. EOS means End of Sentence and it's a token used to indicate the end of a sentence. Every sentence is going to have an EOS token. SOS means Start of Sentence and is used to indicate the start of a sentence.)
        self.n_words = 2 #Intial number of tokens (EOS and SOS)
        
    def addWord(self, word):
        if word not in self.word2int:
            self.word2int[word] = self.n_words
            self.word2count[word] = 1
            self.int2word[self.n_words] = word
            self.n_words += 1
            
        else:
            self.word2count[word] += 1
    
    def addSentence(self, sentence):
        for word in sentence.split(" "):
            self.addWord(word)
```

```
def unicodeToAscii(s):
    return "".join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize("NFD", s) \
                   if unicodedata.category(c) != "Mn")
```

```
def normalizeString(s):
    s = unicodeToAscii(s.lower().strip())
    s = re.sub(r"([!.?])", r" \1", s)
    s = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z?.!]+", " ", s)
    return s
```

```
def load_dataset():
    with open("en_fr.txt",'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    
    pairs = [[normalizeString(pair) for pair in 
              line.strip().split('\t')] for line in lines]
    return pairs
```

```
def sentencetoIndexes(sentence, lang):
    indexes = [lang.word2int[word] for word in sentence.split()]
    indexes.append(EOS_token)
    return indexes
```

```
SOS_token = 0
EOS_token = 1
pairs = load_dataset()
MAX_LENGTH = 50
def sentencetoIndexes(sentence, lang):
    indexes = [lang.word2int[word] for word in sentence.split()]
    indexes.append(EOS_token)
    return indexes

def filterPair(p):
    try:
        return len(p[0].split(' ')) < MAX_LENGTH and len(p[1].split(' ')) < MAX_LENGTH
    except:
        return False


def filterPairs(pairs):
    return [pair for pair in range(len(pairs)) if filterPair(pair)]

pairs = filterPairs(pairs)
```

```
def build_lang(lang1, lang2, max_length=50):
    input_lang = Lang(lang1)
    output_lang = Lang(lang2)
    input_seq = []
    output_seq = []
    
    for pair in pairs:
        input_lang.addSentence(pair[1])
        output_lang.addSentence(pair[0])
    for pair in pairs:
        input_seq.append(sentencetoIndexes(pair[1], input_lang))
        output_seq.append(sentencetoIndexes(pair[0], output_lang))
    return ( 
             keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(input_seq, maxlen=max_length, padding='post', truncating='post'), 
             keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(output_seq, padding='post', truncating='post'), 
             input_lang, output_lang
           )
```

And when doing

```
input_tensor, output_tensor, input_lang, output_lang = build_lang('en', 'fra')
```

Gives this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-259feac15862> in <module>
----> 1 input_tensor, output_tensor, input_lang, output_lang = build_lang('en', 'fra')

<ipython-input-10-d20934657bc2> in build_lang(lang1, lang2, max_length)
     12         output_seq.append(sentencetoIndexes(pair[0], output_lang))
     13     return keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(input_seq, maxlen=max_length, padding='post',
---> 14                                                       truncating='post'), keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(output_seq, padding='post', truncating='post'), input_lang, output_lang

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\sequence.py in pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen, dtype, padding, truncating, value)
    154           or in case of invalid shape for a `sequences` entry.
    155   """
--> 156   return sequence.pad_sequences(
    157       sequences, maxlen=maxlen, dtype=dtype,
    158       padding=padding, truncating=truncating, value=value)

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\sequence.py in pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen, dtype, padding, truncating, value)
     75 
     76     if maxlen is None:
---> 77         maxlen = np.max(lengths)
     78 
     79     is_dtype_str = np.issubdtype(dtype, np.str_) or np.issubdtype(dtype, np.unicode_)

<__array_function__ internals> in amax(*args, **kwargs)

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in amax(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial, where)
   2665     5
   2666     """
-> 2667     return _wrapreduction(a, np.maximum, 'max', axis, None, out,
   2668                           keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)
   2669 

c:\users\zealottv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapreduction(obj, ufunc, method, axis, dtype, out, **kwargs)
     88                 return reduction(axis=axis, out=out, **passkwargs)
     89 
---> 90     return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
     91 
     92 

ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

The [full code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1URAu82Zxr1jplyOEVcOnm4eh2EeC5bfe) can be downloaded here.

Comment: Accepted practice is to include all relevant code within the question rather than including a link to the code

Comment: For instance, you have an error in using `filter_pairs` because you expect it to return a list of lists each with 2 string elements, when instead it returns a list of ints.

Comment: But you haven't included this code in the question.

Comment: I added the rest of the code. (I wrote it in Jupiter Notebook)

Sorry for the mistakes, it's just the first time I'm here!

Comment: No problem, just advising for future questions. But note that my previous comment about `filter_pairs` is still valid

Comment: I tried to rewrite this function, but it keeps giving the given error

`def filterPairs(pairs):
    pairs = []
    for pair in range(len(pairs)):
        pairs.append(pair)
    return pairs`

Comment: The error arises when an empty array is passed to `np.max()` in the line `maxlen = np.max( x )` which is called in `sequence.padSequences()`. Make sure that none of the arrays are empty. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593564/python-how-to-check-if-a-nested-list-is-essentially-empty) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter_pairs()` returns the indices of all pairs that should be included. So I think what you actually want to do is:

```
filter_idxs = filter_pairs(pairs)
keep_pairs = []
for idx in filter_idxs:
   keep_pairs.append(pairs[idx])
```

`keep_pairs` then gives the pairs that should be kept rather than their indices.

I tried manually overwriting pairs with:

```
pairs = [["test","test2"],["test3","test4"]]
```

and was able to evaluate the code without error. `build_lang` expects `pairs` to be a list of lists, each sublist containing 2 strings. So verify that whatever `pairs` is matches this template before it is passed to `build_lang` or you will get an error.

As an aside, you should pass `pairs` as an argument to `build_lang` rather than relying on having defined it in a previous code block; this works in some cases but if you say, run blocks out of order, it may produce undesirable results or errors.

```
def build_lang(lang1,lang2,pairs,max_length = 50):
    ...
```